# Ajax call to fetch new JSON data to update Django template

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, django

I've been trying to figure out the problem for the past hours with no luck.

I want for my django template to load new json data to the user' screen when the user is near the bottom. Basically I want to make my django app load content as I scroll.

This is how I increment the offset to get new data from the api

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
   alert("Requesting new data");
   offset++;
   $.post('/releases/fetch/', {'offset': offset}, function(data){
        console.log("---")
        console.log(data);
        console.log("---")
   });
 }
});
```

I do get the new JSON I want, so ajax's post works well and the offset increments. Now with this new JSON I got, I want to render the rest of my template or rather I want to render the JSON I got as dom elements to my page.

This is the django view I call for my aja's post

```
def ajax_view(request):
if request.is_ajax():
    offset = request.POST['offset']
    games = services.get_games(offset)
    return HttpResponse(games)
return HttpResponse("Get out!! 404")
```

SO do I call django's render instead the HttpResponse?

Oh and this is the django class view that renders the template I'm talking about

```
class HomePage(TemplateView):
  def get(self, request):
    # Sends the json to the template
    games = services.get_games(0)
    return render(request, 'releases/game_list.html', {"games": games})
```

Thanks!

Comment: are you returning ajax or a view ?

Comment: Why can't you just use the same code? It's doing exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try rendering the template in your view and send it back in  `HttpResponse`.

```
from django.template import loader, Context

def ajax_view(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        offset = request.POST['offset']
        games = services.get_games(offset)
        template = loader.get_template('releases/game_list.html')
        context = {"games": games}
        rendered_content = template.render(context)
        return HttpResponse(rendered_content)
    return HttpResponse("Get out!! 404")
```